# How to detect if a page has updated its content?

Tags: javascript, facebook, console

I'm making a javascript code, using it in the console now, but maybe I'll turn it to an extension later, it creates a checkbox besides every Facebook friend in this list: `[https://mobile.facebook.com/[Your Username]/friends]`

First the script needs to scroll down until it loads all friends, then append the checkboxes. Problem is I can't tell the script when to stop scrolling, the only way is to detect if the page has been updated or not, and I don't know how to do this?

**What I tried**

**First Approach**

My first idea was to give the user the ability to choose how many friends to load, and then load friends until the input number is smaller than the number of loaded friends

```
x = parseInt(prompt("How many friends you wanna load?"))
friends = document.querySelectorAll('._55wp._7om2._5pxa._8yo0[data-sigil="undoable-action"]')
scrolling = (n) => {
    if(x < 0 || x > 5000) return console.log("invalide number");
    console.log(n + " friends loaded")
    if(n < x) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 9999999);
            friends = document.querySelectorAll('._55wp._7om2._5pxa._8yo0[data-sigil="undoable-action"]');
            scrolling(friends.length)
        }, 3000)
    }
    else 
    {
        // create_checkboxes();
    }
}
scrolling(friends.length)
```

The problem with this approach is: the user may give an unreasonable number, for instance if he has 500 friends, and give as an input that he wants to load 600 friends, it will be an infinite loop because the number `friends.length` will never be greater than the input. And the script can't get how many friends a user has.

**Second Approach**

I thought about specifying the number of iterations, by my calculations 139 iterations would be enough to load 5000 friends, but this has two problems:
First one which is pretty clear, it'd be a waste of time for those who has just few friends.
Second one, if the internet is slow maybe after 3 seconds of waiting (check the setTimeOut) the friends won't be loaded, therefore maybe even 139 iterations won't be enough and the script wouldn't know.

so my only hope is a way to detect if Facebook made that change and loaded more friends or not, maybe a way to detect if the dom has changed, or even a way to detect if the page didn't made an XHR after it hit the down of the page, this latter way isn't good tho because it may be just because of slow internet.

Comment: if anyone is interested, here's the code I made, it's a tool to unfriend multiple friends at the same time in Facebook. https://github.com/AymaneHrouch/unfriend-multiple/blob/master/tm.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the list, Facebook maintains a div with the class `seeMoreFriends`, which is only present when there are more friends to load:

```
<div class="seeMoreFriends acw apl" id="m_more_friends" data-sigil="marea">
  <div style="text-align:center;" class="centeredIndicator">
    <div class="_2so _2sq _2ss img _50cg" data-animtype="1" id="u_6_11" data-sigil="m-loading-indicator-animate m-loading-indicator-root"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this information, you can check the presence of this div, and if it exists, you know you can continue to scroll, otherwise, you can stop scrolling. Using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) you will know when to check the presence of the above div for each new load:

```
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  const moreFriends = document.querySelector(".seeMoreFriends");
  if (moreFriends) {
    moreFriends.scrollIntoView();
  } else {
    observer.disconnect();
    addCheckboxs();
  }
}

const addCheckboxs = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('._55wp._7om2._5pxa._8yo0[data-sigil="undoable-action"]').forEach(item => {
    item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input type="checkbox">')
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => { // If running in the console the page would have already been loaded, so you can run the callback code directly
  const loader = document.querySelector(".seeMoreFriends");
  if (loader) { // if more friends to load
    const obs = new MutationObserver(callback);
    obs.observe(document.querySelector("._2pit"), {
      childList: true
    }); // listen to changes on the container div of the friends list (holding the seeMoreFriends div and friends list divs)
    loader.scrollIntoView(); // kick off the loading, which will then trigger the mutation observer callback as the page continues to laod
  } else {
    addCheckboxs();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the height of the div in which friends are loaded. And continue scrolling down. Until the height stops changing, you should know that all friends are loaded and there is nothing else to load.Or you could just store how many friends does the account have in a variable and check how many friend div's are there. If the friend divs' count reach the friend count, you are good to go.